# Magento 2: SQLSTATE [22003] Error occurring when deleting product from Admin

Tags: magento2, database, sql, admin-panel

I'm trying to exclude two specific products from Admin, but I've ever seemed this message below:

```
SQLSTATE [22003]: Numeric value out of range 1690 BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in...
```

[image: Magento 2: SQLSTATE 22003]

How could I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this SQL below to solve it:

```
UPDATE `quote` SET `items_count` = '1' where `items_count`='0';
```